# How to get test execution report after JUnitCore.runClasses

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, junit, junit-toolbox

I have following code to start my class methods in parallel:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Class[] cls = {OrderPlacementCancelTest.class};
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(false, true), cls);
}
```

I understand that `runClasses` returns `Result` but I don't understand how can I get test run report. looks like `Result` can it.